# How to get search event option in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to add an Event search option in full calendar. Suggest me if there is an inbuilt option for client-side searching.

Comment: We’re not here to do your research or read the documentation of the tools you are using for you. Show us what your research has turned up so far.

Comment: I was read full documentation for the Full calendar in this https://fullcalendar.io/ link. But I didn't get any solution.

Comment: Then create your own search

Comment: Google [full calendar search events site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=full+calendar+search+events+site:stackoverflow.com) should be able to get you some basic inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any specific frameworks? 
You need to build your own search-module, you can use

```
calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

to refetch the events.

I advise you to filter the elements in your php Model/Repository, assuming you are using php in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this solution

Comment: Sure thing! If you need more assistance let me know.